# Applying a torn effect on a text rectangle in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have the following text rectangle in InDesign, to which I would like to apply an effect that looks like it was torn, on the bottom.

[image]

The most I could do, is to add a rule below to the last paragraph, but this doesn't look good at all. Is there any way to change the appearance of the bottom border of a text rectangle in InDesign?

Comment: I don't believe this is (easily) accomplished via InDesign. You'd have to draw it with the Pen tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an anchor object:

- Five grouped wavy paths, the four bottoms with the paper stroke color (yellow in the example image)
- Set the anchor object wide, position and leading

[image: Anchor object]

[image: Anchor object]